.NET MAUI ApplePay + Stripe
I want to implement Apple pay payments with Stripe payment gateway in my .net MAUI mobile application, however it is extremely hard to find needed information on how to do that, expecially there is no complete guide on how to implement such things.
Did someone had experience with such things? Could you please describe how to complete the stripe Apple pay payment.
No information found.

Please read [ask] before posting
